# How do I save/lock specific comment bubbles within a text message thread?

Tags: sms, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-e, google-messages

Is it possible to make the downloaded SMS application, "Google Messenger" save just part of a thread in a text conversation on my Moto E Android phone?

Example: I'm chatting back and forth with a friend, a long thread, a long conversation.  In one comment bubble, my friend gives me an important address that I want to lock and save, but I want to delete the rest of the thread (all the other bubbles).

I used to be able to do this on an older android phone.  It had a different sms app.  I don't remember what that app was, but I could delete my entire inbox with the exception of specific comments/bubbles on which I had put locks/saves.

My current phone model number is Moto E (2nd Generation) with 4G LTE.

OS is lollipop 5.1 (I think)

Comment: Please add OS version and the SMS application you are using-whether stock or downloaded

Comment: My operating system number  5.7.14.19.arm Legal. My SMS application is messenger (Google Messenger) downloaded.

Comment: I meant OS VERSION like KitKat, lollipop etc denoted by 4.4.2 or 5.x.x. you will find that information in *settings&rarr; about phone* . Edit your question to reflect that so that it is visible instead of searching in comments

Comment: Thank you for your help beeshyams.  I appreciate your efforts.  I ended up scrapping google messenger and using an app called textra instead.  It is working great for me.  I am very technologically challenged.  I appreciate anyone who is willing to try and help a luggernut like me :)

Comment: Oh, and I think my OS is lollipop 5.1  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes. You can answer your own question with the solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question in your post when you said that you used to be able to do this, but had a different SMS app.

This function, as far as I know, is app specific. I am able to lock messages using ChompSMS on Android 5.0.

Try different SMS apps and see which is best for your needs.

Comment: Thank you Verdant Drift.  Your response was very helpful.